# Why were limits introduced in calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, motivation

I have got the intuitive of the limits but why were they introduced in calculus, are they really helpful to us?

Comment: Calculus is based off of the idea of limits. The fact they are introduced together just shows that your teachers are trying to show how calculus works.

Comment: Without limits, there are no derivatives, and without derivatives there are no integrals.

Answer (score 2):

Of course they are helpful in calculus. Calculus cannot be formulated without limits, as essentially, calculus is the theory of infinitesimals as $\Delta x\to 0$.

You define the differential as a limit:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
You define the integral as a limit:
$$\int^b_af(x)\operatorname{d}x=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}L_n=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}R_n$$
Where $L_n,R_n$ are the left and right Riemann sums respectively. You will also encounter limits in topology.

Comment: Can't you do calculus with infinitesimals? I don't think anyone teaches it this way though as the non-standard analysis behind it can be rather scary.

Comment: @ruler501 You could do calculus with infinitesimals - however, the level of accuracy of calculus cannot be replicated by infinitesimals.

Comment: What is a result that cannot be obtained without the concept of limits?

Comment: [Keisler's textbook "Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach"](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html) formulates plenty of calculus without limits.

Comment: @SanathK.Devalapurkar That's simply not true - calculus via infinitesimals (e.g. nonstandard analysis) is as accurate as classical calculus, and indeed in certain senses stronger. This is **not** to say that it's superior pedagogically - that's a whole different debate - but it's completely wrong to say that it's less accurate.